# How to turn one symbol into another

Tags: r

Im trying to find a way to substitute out the "|" symbol in this dataset for the "/" symbol
df<-c(2|4,5|6,3|4,4|7,5|8)
So that way the final would look like
df<-c(2/4,5/6,3/4,4/7,5/8)

Any help would be great thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a single string (or a vector of elements) use `chartr` from `base R`

```
chartr("|", "/", df)
[1] "2/4,5/6,3/4,4/7,5/8"
df2$col1 <- chartr("|", "/", df2$col1)
> df2
  col1
1  2/4
2  5/6
3  3/4
4  4/7
5  5/8
```

#### data

```
df <- "2|4,5|6,3|4,4|7,5|8"
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("2|4", "5|6", "3|4", "4|7", "5|8"))
```

Comment: Sorry it's like a dataframe so each set of numbers i.e. (2|4) is its own row in a table

Comment: @RobertS it wouldn't matter i.e. `df <- data.frame(col1 = c("2|4", "5|6")); df$col1 <- chartr("|", "/", df$col1)`